# Stop state_pressed working for parent when hitting a view inside of it

Tags: android, android-selector

I have a `ListView` with quite complex items. Each item among some other elements has a `RelativeLayout` inside of it (let's call it additionalPanel). When I hit the area of an item I want to change its background, but only if the area I hit doesn't belong to additionalPanel. If I hit additionalPanel I don't want to do anything.

I created two selectors for both item and additionalPanel hoping that if selector for additionalPanel fires, another one won't, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Even if I hit additionalPanel the whole item still changes its background.

I tried to set `android:clickable="true"` for additionalPanel, but it only stopped items from receiving `onClick` event. `android:focusable=true"` doesn't work either.

Item selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alarm_item_pressed_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alarm_item_regular_background"/>
```

AdditionalPanel selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So no ideas? There should be some kind of workaround